# Wordpress running on EC2 t3.small becomes unavailable (ELB Error 504) after X amount of time, needs rebooting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a problem with my Amazon EC2 instance (that did not happened when I was using DigitalOcean).

I've several EC2 instances that are managed by me. My personal EC2 has about 5 Wordpress sites running on a t2.micro instance and the traffic is not high so it is working well in load speed.

Also I have another 2 instances for one of my clients, one t2.micro (running only one Wordpress site) and a t3a.micro (running 4 Wordpress sites). The issue is with all 3 instances (mine and all the 2 of my client).

I have a CloudWatch alarm to notify me by email when Error 504 happen. Since I get the alarm, the website becomes unavailable (Cloudflare shows me Error 504), but I can get into SSH or Webmin. I do `service nginx status` and all seems to be fine, same to `service php7.2-fpm`. I do `pkill nginx && pkill php*` and then `service nginx start && service php7.2-fpm start` correctly but when I try to enter to the site, the Error 504 is still there.

To test, I decided to install and configure Apache with and without PHP-FPM enabled, same problem. Instance going well and websites running fast but after X amount of hours, it becomes unaccessible via web and the only solution is rebooting...

What's the only thing that solve the issue? Well, rebooting the instance.... After it boots, the websites are available again. Please note that I moved from DigitalOcean to AWS because it is more useful but I can't understand why the problem is happening here and not there since I've a similar instance configured very similar...

In all of the instances I've a setup with:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 18.04
- **Types**: Two t2.micro and one t3a.micro
- **ELB**: Enabled
- **Security Groups**: only allow ports 80, 443 from all the sources.
- **Database**: In a RDS, not on the same instance.

I can provide the logs of everything that you probably can ask but I review all the Nginx and PHP-fpm logs and I can't see any anomalies. Also with `syslog` and `kern.log`, but I can provide if it can helps.

Hope you can give me a hand. Thanks for your advice!

EDIT:

I already found the origin of the issue. The problem wasn't in the EC2, all my headache was because I have the RDS set with only one Security Group attached to allow access from my IP to remote management of the databases and the public IPs of the EC2 that runs Wordpress, but I figured that I also need to whitelist the private IPs of those EC2s... Really noob mistake but that was the solution.

Comment: Have you observed an increased usage of ram on instances (for metrics, need to install CloudWatch agent), or some "strange" metrics for RDS?

Comment: How is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Here are several AWS technicians answering questions and also I added the tags to identify the topic of the question... Also here are another questions about AWS and their services @KenWhite

Comment: @Marcin I think I found the solution... None of the problems were in the EC2, the solution was adding the private IP of the EC2 to the only Security Group attached to the RDS (that previously has the public IP of the EC2 and my IP for remote access only), since that, the instance was working well for a day. If another 504 error happen, I'll update you, but tomorrow I'll edit the question adding that solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Ciphreak Thanks for letting me know. Hope it will be working fine now.